# Error : invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get this error:

Unhandled exception at line 993, column 29 in http://localhost:1810/Titulares/Create?Length=9

0x800a03f6 - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: Carácter no válido (JavaScript Runtime Error : Invalid character)

The line 993 is:

```
var response = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
```

And all code is:

```
function Ajax_EstadoEmpresa(dataToSend) {
    debugger;
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Titulares/EstadoEmpresa",
        data: jsonStr,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            Success_EstadoEmpresa(result);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            var response = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            if (response.Message) {
                alert(response.Message);
            } else {
                alert(textStatus);
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try by not using JSON.parse

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to parse to json what is already a json. Besides, the invalid character is probably in your data (returning an invalid json), not in your code itself.

Comment: thanks! but dont entry in succes, now show an alert because enters here: else { alert(textStatus); };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `JSON.parse` since you already mentioned in datatype it as "JSON".Please remove that and try executing.

Comment: now show an alert because enters here: else {
                alert(textStatus);
            };